# Probability distribution of vectors obtained from Gram-Schmidt process on i.i.d. Gaussian vectors

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian, orthogonal-groups

Given $N$ vectors in $K$ dimensions that are independently and identically distributed according to a Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation equal to an identity matrix, what is the probability distribution of the vectors obtained by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to the original set of vectors?

Answer (score 5):

The orthogonalization requires $N\leq K$. For $N=K$ the resulting $N\times N$ unitary matrix is distributed according to the Haar measure, see [On asymptotics of large Haar distributed unitary matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310338) (page 3-4). For $N<K$ you would have a submatrix of a Haar-distributed matrix.